# Oracle's UTL_TCP Equivalent in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, plsql

I received a function from a co worker as a solution for a problem I'm facing with one of our applications that included reference to the Oracle Library UTL_TCP (write_text). However, the solution is not yet one since I'm not actually using Oracle, but SQL Server 2005. I've been able to convert most of the code to Transact SQL syntax, but still haven't found the equivalent for this library in SQL Server.

I know UTL_TCP.write_text just sends a message to a service on another server (parameters include host, port and charset).

Any possible ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post what you've converted to TSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has no built-in support for using sockets from TSQL code. The most obvious solution is to write your own CLR stored procedure(s) to wrap the System.Net.Sockets.Socket class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
Any examples on how to use that class in T-SQL?

Comment: No, but the point of a CLR procedure is that it's written entirely in .NET and you then call it like any other stored procedure. So TSQL isn't really the issue here; you should focus on designing and coding the .NET part: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094(v=SQL.90).aspx